# Run a new task in Airflow Kubernetes with it's own isolated Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, dagster

How do I run a new pipeline with it's own isolated Dockerfile in Airflow Kubernetes ?

I've been using Dagster and I can run new pipelines on their own Dockerfile, but can't figure out how to do this in Airflow

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a docker container task on Kubernetes using Airflow, regardless the executor you are using and how you deployed Airflow server, you can use [KubernetesPodOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html).

You can specify the docker image by providing the argument `image`, you can also override the image entrypoint and provide extra args (`cmds` and `arguments`). And you can configure your pod as you need (labesl, volumes, secrets, configMaps, ...).